# How to send jquery array value in $.post

Tags: php, jquery

I'm u using this code in jquery below :-

```
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $get_result['pid'] ;?>" name="get_id[]" id="get_id" />


    var values = $("input[name='get_id[]']").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
```

However when I'm using `$.post` to send this data then its showing `array` type error. Could someone please help me. How can I properly send this data to a PHP page by $.post?

```
var url = "<?php echo "result.php"; ?>";
$.post(url, { sql_id: values }, function(data) { 
    $('#output').html(data);
});
});
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with sending data this way. What makes you think it's 'improper'? I would assume the issue lies in your PHP code, but you haven't included that in your question, so no one can help you.

Comment: You should seriously consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: My above code showing output "ARRAY" even when I'm alert it its showing proper data.

Comment: I have modified my question. please help me !!

Comment: show the exact error message  you get ..

Comment: Its showing "ARRAY" Message ,  That means the array data is not sending.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not `json.stringify(values)` before sending it to the PHP file ?